# unable to move 5million URL from forum/abc/ to forums/abc/

Tags: mod-rewrite

I had a forum with `/forum` but it has changed to `/forums` I want to know if there is a single line code which can redirect my old URL to new ones. It is not simple redirection from `/forum` to `/forums` The URL after `/forum/abc.html` are now `/forums/abc.html` There are some 500000 URL that need to be changed. Could anybody help

For example

`example.com/forum/topic/144934-pio-threatened-rti-applicant/` is now `example.com/forums/topic/144934-pio-threatened-rti-applicant/`

If you see above the change is just 'S' for all the 500000 URLs

I have already tried this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ /forums/$1 [NC,L]
```

I am left with permanent redirection only I am trying this way

```
Redirect 301 /forum/42534-how-know-my-pf-account-no.html /forums/42534-how-know-my-pf-account-no.html
```

Comment: In what _context_ are these directives? `.htaccess`? `<Directory>` container? Server config or `<VirtualHost>` container?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ /forums/$1 [NC,L]
> ```

This is an *internal rewrite*, not a *redirect*. You need to add the `R` flag to make it an *external redirect*. Otherwise, this should work OK (depending on the *context* it is being used - you don't actually say). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^/?forum/(.*)$ /forums/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

And make sure this appears before any conflicting directives. (eg. If it's in `.htaccess` then this should usually go at the top.)

However, you only need a simple mod_alias `Redirect`, unless you already have existing mod_rewrite directives (which could result in conflicts). For example:

```
Redirect 301 /forum /forums
```

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching, copying everything after the match onto the end of the target URL. eg. `/forum/foo` is redirected to `/forums/foo`, etc. And only matches whole path segments, so this avoids a redirect loop.

As always, make sure you clear the browser cache before testing and test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching problems.